# pygameでテキストが更新されない

Tags: python, python3, macos, pygame

私は今pygameでゲーム作りをしています。
画面上にスコアを表示したいのですが、なぜか `score = 0` のまま止まってしまいます。
クラスの中では一応スコアは増えているのですが...
わかる方いましたらご回答お願いします。

全コード

```
import pygame
from setting import *
import time
import random

pygame.init()

#明るさのクラス--------------------------------
class Backgrou():
    alpha = 0     
    Bacgro_time = 0
    def trans(self):

        if self.Bacgro_time == 42:
            #print(self.alpha)
            self.Bacgro_time = 0
            self.alpha += 1
            
    def Background_time(self, surface):
        self.Bacgro_time += 1
        img = pygame.image.load('黒い四角形3.png').convert_alpha()
        rect = img.get_rect(center=(400,400))
        img.set_alpha(self.alpha)
        surface.blit(img, rect)

#-------------------------------------------------

#プレイヤーのクラス-----------------------------------------------------------------
class PlayerSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    player_time = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlayerSprite, self).__init__()

        self.images = list()
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_0.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_2.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_5.png'))
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        
    def update(self):
        self.player_time += 1

        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        if self.player_time == 4:
            self.index += 1
            self.player_time = 0
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(player_x,670))
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (256,256))

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#背景（周りの草）のクラス---------------------------------------------------------------

class KusaSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    kusa_time = 0
    kusa_time2 = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(KusaSprite,self).__init__()

        self.images = list()
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa0.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa2.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa5.png'))
        self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.image2 = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
    def update(self):
        self.kusa_time += 1

        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        if self.kusa_time == 5:
            self.index += 1
            self.kusa_time = 0
        
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(200,800))

class KusaSprite2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    kusa_time = 0
    kusa_time2 = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(KusaSprite2,self).__init__()

        self.images = list()
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa0.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa2.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa5.png'))
        self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.image2 = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(600,0))
        
    def update(self):
        self.kusa_time += 1

        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        if self.kusa_time == 5:
            self.index += 1
            self.kusa_time = 0
        
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(200,800))

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

#小石のクラス-------------------------------------------------------------------------
class KoishiSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    score = 0
    
    #小石クラスの時間
    koishi_time = 0
    koishi_speed = 5
    koishi_level = [5,15]

    koishi_speed2 = 5
    koishi_level2 = [5,15]

    #小石の場所についての変数
    koishi_x = 400
    koishi_y = 0

    koishi_x2 = 400
    koishi_y2 = 0

    koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(koishi_x,655,50,50)
    koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(koishi_x,655,50,50)
                
    def update(self,player_rect):

        self.koishi_y += self.koishi_speed
        
        self.koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x,self.koishi_y,25,20)
        #pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,self.koishi_rect)

        self.koishi_img = pygame.image.load('koishi.png')
        self.koishi_img = pygame.transform.scale(self.koishi_img,(64,64))
        screen.blit(self.koishi_img,pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x - 20,self.koishi_y - 20,25,20))
        
        if player_rect.colliderect(self.koishi_rect):
            print('衝突')
            self.koishi_y = 0
            self.koishi_x = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed = random.randint(self.koishi_level[0],self.koishi_level[1])

        if self.koishi_y >= 800:
            self.score += 1
            self.koishi_y = 0
            self.koishi_x = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed = random.randint(self.koishi_level[0],self.koishi_level[1])
    
    def update2(self,player_rect):

        self.koishi_y2 += self.koishi_speed2
        
        self.koishi_rect2 = pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x2,self.koishi_y2,25,20)
        #pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,self.koishi_rect2)

        self.koishi_img2 = pygame.image.load('koishi.png')
        self.koishi_img2 = pygame.transform.scale(self.koishi_img2,(64,64))
        screen.blit(self.koishi_img2,pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x2 - 20,self.koishi_y2 - 20,25,20))
        
        if player_rect.colliderect(self.koishi_rect2):
            print('衝突')
            self.koishi_y2 = 0
            self.koishi_x2 = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed2 = random.randint(self.koishi_level2[0],self.koishi_level2[1])

        if self.koishi_y2 >= 800:
            self.score += 1
            self.koishi_y2 = 0
            self.koishi_x2 = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed2 = random.randint(self.koishi_level2[0],self.koishi_level2[1])
        
        #スコアのテキスト
        print(self.score)
        
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)

#プレイヤーのx座標
player_x = 335

#ウィンドウの設定---------
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 800

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('石よけよ！')
#-------------

#スプライトのオブジェクトを作ってグループ化------
#プレイヤー
player = PlayerSprite()
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

#小石
koishi = KoishiSprite()
koishi_group = pygame.sprite.Group(koishi)

#背景
kusa = KusaSprite()
kusa_group = pygame.sprite.Group(kusa)
kusa2 = KusaSprite2()
kusa_group2 = pygame.sprite.Group(kusa2)

#----------------------------------------

#線を描画---------
def draw_line():
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,(200,0),(200,800),3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,(600,0),(600,800),3)

#----------------

#FPS--------
FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#-----------

bg = Backgrou()

#ロゴ
logo_rect = pygame.Rect(80,50,300,200)
logo_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_logo.png')
logo_img = pygame.transform.scale(logo_img,(600,400))

#ボタン設定-------------------------------------------------
#スタートボタン
start_button_rect = pygame.Rect(300,500,200,60)
start_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_start_button.png')

#難易度設定
#easy
easy_button_rect = pygame.Rect(300,400,200,60)
easy_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_easy_button.png')
#normal
normal_button_rect = pygame.Rect(300,500,200,60)
normal_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_normal_button.png')
#hard
hard_button_rect = pygame.Rect(300,600,200,60)
hard_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_hard_button.png')

#---------------------------------------------------------

#今どの場面か
#レベル設定（Falseならスタート画面）
select_level = False

game_time = 0

game_start = False

#メインループ=================================================
run = True
while run:

    game_time += 1

    #テキストの設定
    
    screen.fill((0,200,0))
    if game_start == True:
        draw_line()

    if game_start == False:
        if select_level == False:
            screen.blit(start_button_img,start_button_rect)
            
        if select_level == True:
            screen.blit(easy_button_img,easy_button_rect)
            screen.blit(normal_button_img,normal_button_rect)
            screen.blit(hard_button_img,hard_button_rect)

        screen.blit(logo_img,logo_rect)

    #プレイヤーの当たり判定
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_x + 37,662,40,108)
    #pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,player_rect)

    #小石のプログラムの実行
    if game_start == True:
        koishi.update(player_rect)
        koishi.update2(player_rect)

    #プレイヤー
    if game_start == True:
        player_group.update()
        player_group.draw(screen)      

    #草
    if game_start == True:
        kusa_group.update()
        kusa_group.draw(screen)
        kusa_group2.update()
        kusa_group2.draw(screen)
        
    #背景
    if game_start == True:
        bg.trans()
        bg.Background_time(screen)

    if game_start == True:
        print(KoishiSprite.score)
        text_score = font.render('score = ' + str(KoishiSprite.score),True,WHITE)
        screen.blit(text_score,(30,30))

    #イベントの取得
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if start_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                if select_level == False:

                    game_time = 0
                    select_level = True
                    pygame.mixer.music.load('決定ボタンを押す22.mp3')
                    pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
                    print('Start')
            if game_time >= 5:
                if easy_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if select_level == True:

                        game_start = True
                        
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[0] = 3
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[1] = 10

                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[0] = 3
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[1] = 10

                        pygame.mixer.music.load('決定ボタンを押す22.mp3')
                        pygame.mixer_music.play(1)
                        print('Easy game start!')
                    
                if normal_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if select_level == True:
                        
                        game_start = True
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[0] = 5
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[1] = 15

                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[0] = 5
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[1] = 15

                        pygame.mixer.music.load('決定ボタンを押す22.mp3')
                        pygame.mixer_music.play(1)
                        print('Normal game start!')
                
                if hard_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if select_level == True:

                        game_start = True
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[0] = 10
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[1] = 20

                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[0] = 10
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[1] = 20

                        pygame.mixer.music.load('決定ボタンを押す22.mp3')
                        pygame.mixer_music.play(1)
                        print('Hard game start!')
                    
    #プレイヤーのキー入力
    if game_start == True:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and not player_x == 165:
            player_x -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not player_x == 520:
            player_x += 5
    
    #画面の更新とFPSの設定
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

#===========================================================

pygame.quit()
```

問題のクラス

```
class KoishiSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    score = 0
    
    #小石クラスの時間
    koishi_time = 0
    koishi_speed = 5
    koishi_level = [5,15]

    koishi_speed2 = 5
    koishi_level2 = [5,15]

    #小石の場所についての変数
    koishi_x = 400
    koishi_y = 0

    koishi_x2 = 400
    koishi_y2 = 0

    koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(koishi_x,655,50,50)
    koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(koishi_x,655,50,50)

    def update(self,player_rect):

        self.koishi_y += self.koishi_speed
        
        self.koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x,self.koishi_y,25,20)
        #pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,self.koishi_rect)

        self.koishi_img = pygame.image.load('koishi.png')
        self.koishi_img = pygame.transform.scale(self.koishi_img,(64,64))
        screen.blit(self.koishi_img,pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x - 20,self.koishi_y - 20,25,20))
        
        if player_rect.colliderect(self.koishi_rect):
            print('衝突')
            self.koishi_y = 0
            self.koishi_x = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed = random.randint(self.koishi_level[0],self.koishi_level[1])

        if self.koishi_y >= 800:
            self.score += 1
            self.koishi_y = 0
            self.koishi_x = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed = random.randint(self.koishi_level[0],self.koishi_level[1])
    
    def update2(self,player_rect):

        self.koishi_y2 += self.koishi_speed2
        
        self.koishi_rect2 = pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x2,self.koishi_y2,25,20)
        #pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,self.koishi_rect2)

        self.koishi_img2 = pygame.image.load('koishi.png')
        self.koishi_img2 = pygame.transform.scale(self.koishi_img2,(64,64))
        screen.blit(self.koishi_img2,pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x2 - 20,self.koishi_y2 - 20,25,20))
   
        if player_rect.colliderect(self.koishi_rect2):
            print('衝突')
            self.koishi_y2 = 0
            self.koishi_x2 = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed2 = random.randint(self.koishi_level2[0],self.koishi_level2[1])

        if self.koishi_y2 >= 800:
            self.score += 1
            self.koishi_y2 = 0
            self.koishi_x2 = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed2 = random.randint(self.koishi_level2[0],self.koishi_level2[1])
        
        #スコアのテキスト
        print(self.score)
```

Comment: `text_score = font.render('score = ' + str(KoishiSprite.score),True,WHITE)`を`text_score = font.render('score = ' + str(koishi.score),True,WHITE)`に書き換えるとどうなりますか？